# remove folder in dat.Gui

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I'm using dat.GUI and want to replace a folder with new content.

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
var folder = gui.addFolder('someString');

// sometime later ...
var newFolder = gui.addFolder('someString'); // causes an error
```

So I need a way to remove the previous folder or replace its content.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this out:- https://code.google.com/p/dat-gui/issues/detail?id=21

Comment: Where to integrate this function, and how to call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solution worked for me. You need to add this function to the dat.GUI file or manually add it in your code:

```
dat.GUI.prototype.removeFolder = function(name) {
  var folder = this.__folders[name];
  if (!folder) {
    return;
  }
  folder.close();
  this.__ul.removeChild(folder.domElement.parentNode);
  delete this.__folders[name];
  this.onResize();
}
```

Check it out here: [dat.gui how to hide menu with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710559/dat-gui-how-to-hide-menu-with-code)

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that when we destroy dat.gui using 
dat.gui.destory()
this will not remove all the registered events which could be a bummer for performance.